# how to find 80% of distribution

Tags: r, quantile

A have a problem.
I have a data frame byDays, which consists of two columns: day and money.
Day looks like sequence from 0 to 100. And Money means amount of money, our customers spent in this day. 
I plotted distribution, but cant link it, havent got enough reputation.

And i need to find a day(!) left from which will be 80% of area of my distibution.

Comment: It's hard to offer much help if without some data. Could you provide some sample data? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you mean the cumulative money?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the point at which 80% of the total is reached this will give you the answer:

```
set.seed(1)
day <- 1:100
profit <- runif(100, 0, 15)

##  Point at which 80% of the total is reached:
pct <- max(x[ cumsum(profit)/sum(profit) <= 0.8])

plot(day, cumsum(profit)/sum(profit))
abline(v=pct, col="red")
```

[image: Day at which 80% of total profit is reached]